# JavaCV creating and drawing grayscale one channel histogram

Tags: opencv, histogram, javacv, grayscale

i am new to this website, please let me know if i have made any mistake on my post.
I have some questions regarding calculating and drawing histogram in javacv. Below are the codes that i have written based on some information that i have searched:

There is this error that i get: *OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (index is out of range) in unknown function, file ......\src\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 1691*

```
private CvHistogram getHistogram(IplImage image) {//get histogram data, input has been converted to grayscale beforehand 


    IplImage[] hsvImage1 = {image};
    //bins and value-range
    int numberOfBins = 256;
    float minRange = 0.0f;
    float maxRange = 255.0f;
    // Allocate histogram object
    int dims = 1;
    int[] sizes = new int[]{numberOfBins};
    int histType = CV_HIST_ARRAY;
    float[] minMax = new float[]{minRange, maxRange};
    float[][] ranges = new float[][]{minMax};
    CvHistogram hist = cvCreateHist(dims, sizes, histType, ranges, 1); 
    cvCalcHist(hsvImage1, hist, 0, null);
    return hist;
}

private IplImage DrawHistogram(CvHistogram hist, IplImage image) {//draw histogram
    int scaleX = 1;
    int scaleY = 1;
    int i;
    float[] max_value = {0};
    int[] int_value = {0};
    cvGetMinMaxHistValue(hist, max_value, max_value, int_value, int_value);//get min and max value for histogram

    IplImage imgHist = cvCreateImage(cvSize(256, image.height() ),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);//create image to store histogram
    cvZero(imgHist);
    CvPoint pts = new CvPoint(5);

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {//draw the histogram 
        float value = opencv_legacy.cvQueryHistValue_1D(hist, i);
        float nextValue = opencv_legacy.cvQueryHistValue_1D(hist, i + 1);

        pts.position(0).x(i * scaleX).y(image.height() * scaleY);
        pts.position(1).x(i * scaleX + scaleX).y(image.height() * scaleY);
        pts.position(2).x(i * scaleX + scaleX).y((int)((image.height() - nextValue * image.height() /max_value[0]) * scaleY));
        pts.position(3).x(i * scaleX).y((int)((image.height() - value * image.height() / max_value[0]) * scaleY));
        pts.position(4).x(i * scaleX).y(image.height() * scaleY);
        cvFillConvexPoly(imgHist, pts.position(0), 5, CvScalar.RED, CV_AA, 0);
    }
    return imgHist;
}
```

I have tried searching few links that i provided at the bottom, however, each of them are in different language, therefore i am not sure i have converted them to java correctly. To be honest there are few things i doubt, will be glad if any advice can be provided, such as:

1. float[] max_value = {0}; // i referred to the internet and it helps me to getby syntax error in  cvGetMinMaxHistValue() , not sure if it will cause logic error
2. pts.position(3).x(i * scaleX).y((int)((image.height() - value * image.height() / max_value[0]) * scaleY)); // i put int to downcast it to the type the pts will recognise, and one more thing is max_value[0] is 0, wondering if it will cause logical error due to division

Links used:

Answer (score 0):

//use this
public CvHistogram getHistogram(IplImage image) {//get histogram data, input has been converted to grayscale beforehand

```
IplImageArray hsvImage1 = splitChannels(image);
//bins and value-range
int numberOfBins = 256;
float minRange = 0.0f;
float maxRange = 255.0f;
// Allocate histogram object
int dims = 1;
int[] sizes = new int[]{numberOfBins};
int histType = CV_HIST_ARRAY;
float[] minMax = new float[]{minRange, maxRange};
float[][] ranges = new float[][]{minMax};

CvHistogram hist = cvCreateHist(dims, sizes, histType, ranges, 1); 
cvCalcHist(hsvImage1, hist, 0, null);
return hist;
```

}

```
private IplImageArray splitChannels(IplImage hsvImage) {
    CvSize size = hsvImage.cvSize();
    int depth = hsvImage.depth();
    IplImage channel0 = cvCreateImage(size, depth, 1);
    IplImage channel1 = cvCreateImage(size, depth, 1);
    IplImage channel2 = cvCreateImage(size, depth, 1);
    cvSplit(hsvImage, channel0, channel1, channel2, null);
    return new IplImageArray(channel0, channel1, channel2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in this part:

```
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {//draw the histogram 
    float value = opencv_legacy.cvQueryHistValue_1D(hist, i);
    float nextValue = opencv_legacy.cvQueryHistValue_1D(hist, i + 1);
```

You use `i+1` and it causes the error out of range, you can use your `for` until `255` to correct it.

I hope I helped you. GL